# How to auto increment id in XML using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am generating the below XML using JAXB. Please see below XML

```
<Messages>
   <Message id ="1">
     <lastname>gg</lastname>
     <firstname>cc</firstname>>
    </Message>
    <Message id ="2">
     <lastname>ftrtr</lastname>
     <firstname>mnn</firstname>>
    <Message>
   <Message id ="3">
     <lastname>ftrtr</lastname>
     <firstname>mnn</firstname>>
   <Message>
```

Please observe id, the values are 1,2,3.

I need a provision to increment this value automatically using JAXB.

Please advice

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could map this example with an `XmlAdapter`:

### Java Model

**Message**

Below is the `Message` class.  We will add an `XmlAdapter` to the `id` field:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IDAdapter.class)
    private Integer id = 0;

}
```

**IDAdapter**

Below is the `XmlAdapter` that will adjust the `id` attribute.  See the `Demo` class below for what we need to do to fully utilize this class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class IDAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Integer, Integer> {

    private int counter = 1;

    @Override
    public Integer unmarshal(Integer v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer marshal(Integer v) throws Exception {
        return counter++;
    }

}
```

**Messages**

Here is the remaining class to complete the example.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Messages")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Messages {

    @XmlElement(name="Message")
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

In the demo code below set an instance of `IDAdapter` on the `Marshaller`.  Doing this makes the `IDAdapter` stateful.  If we don't do this a new Instance of `IDAdapter` will be created each time it is used and the output will always be `id="1"`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Messages.class);

        Messages messages = new Messages();
        messages.getMessages().add(new Message());
        messages.getMessages().add(new Message());
        messages.getMessages().add(new Message());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setAdapter(new IDAdapter());
        marshaller.marshal(messages, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Messages>
    <Message id="1"/>
    <Message id="2"/>
    <Message id="3"/>
</Messages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you convert you should be having a `List<Message>` type in the `class Messages`.

You can increment the id using any iteration in the list. After it is incremented you can convert it into XML using JAXB.

Basically you need to increment it based on your requirements before you convert it into xml.

Comment: @dhanpil I would suggest you to go through the answers suggested by Blaise they are more formal and standard way to do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could map this example with an `Marshaller.Listener`:

### Java Model

**Message**

Below is the `Message` class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Message {

    private Integer id = 0;

    @XmlAttribute
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Messages**

Here is the remaining class to complete the example.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Messages")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Messages {

    @XmlElement(name="Message")
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will use a instance of `Marshaller.Listener` to set the value of the `id` property on `Message` before it is marshalled.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Messages.class);

        Messages messages = new Messages();
        messages.getMessages().add(new Message());
        messages.getMessages().add(new Message());
        messages.getMessages().add(new Message());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setListener(new Marshaller.Listener() {

            private int counter = 1;

            public void beforeMarshal(Object object) {
                if(object instanceof Message) {
                    ((Message) object).setId(counter++);
                }
            }

        });
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setAdapter(new IDAdapter());
        marshaller.marshal(messages, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Messages>
    <Message id="1"/>
    <Message id="2"/>
    <Message id="3"/>
</Messages>
```